# Transfer dynamic html file to another language in .net core web api

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send email according to entered language. I have a html template of email. But now I want to convert whole dynamic data of html file according to user's entered language.
[image]

Here, {username} and {email} are dynamic data.
Now if user enters 'Korean' as language name then his username and other content of html file like "Thank you for registering in our system" should be in Korean language when we send this email.

Comment: Don't use "dynamic", it's a buzzword that adds nothing. What is your question? How to translate an email address to Korean? That's not how addresses work.

Comment: There should always be a seperate language option, I for one could temporarily live in Japan or China for work. Yet not speak a single word of the language. Or live in a country which has a dominant language which I might not speak as a minority in said country.

Comment: you could look into `StringLocalizer`. You would have to translate every single email yourself however. I am not aware of automated translations.